# Clear history for Open Resource dialog in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

How can I clear the history of the Open Resource dialog? The history shows all the files you've opened before using the Open Resource dialog, and is shown before you start typing a query in the search field:

[image]

I can't find any way to reset/clear it, and lately it has become cluttered, it contains almost every file in the project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just select an entry and hit <kbd>Delete</kbd>.

Or right click on an entry and choose *Remove from History*.

You can select all of them with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> and remove them with one command.

This works in the JDT *Open Type* dialog too.